# Use everyauth package for authorizing users to access data via REST api calls

Tags: authentication, node.js, oauth, everyauth

I am developing a google chrome extension that needs to communicate with a nodejs server. I was wondering if its possible to use everyauth package to simplify authentication. For starters, I just wanted to use simple password based authentication. But from the examples and the documentation ,as well according to my trial, it seems to me that everyauth is designed to be used for a webapp and gives me errors if i don't set the getLoginPath. Also i am not sure how to configure everyauth to send the user details or errors after user authenticate in a json payroll rather than redirecting user to a particular page. This is my first project with node.js and I am looking for some advice on how to go forward with this. I am open to using some other package/library that provides such authentication,

Answer (score 1):

Since you are open to using other modules, as the developer of Passport, I'd suggest you look at it: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport

Passport is designed to be a simple and unobtrusive authentication library, which makes it easy to get up and running quickly.  It's also modular and extensible, which allows it to adapt to your applications needs over time.

The examples provided, along with the local strategy ( https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local ) are enough to get you started with username/password authentication.  Let me know if you have any feedback or questions.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to use passport RESTfull auth? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572600/passport-js-restful-auth)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish a REST-only interface to everyauth by overriding its handler methods: https://gist.github.com/2938492