# Is it possible to login someone with their facebook account through a restful service?

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js, restify

I ran across [this Node.js example](https://github.com/halrobertson/test-restify-passport-facebook), which makes me think that it is possible, but when I tried to setup the example locally, it doesn't seem to do anything. It would seem to me that it would not be possible, as the login for most of these services, like Facebook Connect and OpenID, require a redirect to the provider's site, then a redirect back to your site.

What I am trying to accomplish in the long-run is to develop an application using a combination of PhoneGap with a Node.js restful backend.  I am not integrating with Facebook, other than to use the login credentials.  I have to admit that my understanding of OAUTH, OpenID, and Facebook Connect is rather novice.  I would like to have my PhoneGap application simply send over the credentials and have my Node.js authenticate them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passport.js RESTful auth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572600/passport-js-restful-auth)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done. I believe the server-side code handles the redirect. Here is a [good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16781555/773263) of the solution.