# Passport.js 2 ways authentication (session and stateless)

Tags: node.js, restful-authentication, mean-stack, passport.js

I am using the MEAN stack for my application. I am using the LocalStrategy to login with an email an a password) for my AngularJS application.
However, I would like to make an Android app that will connect to nodejs threw a stateless authentication (not decided which one yet : oauth, basic, etc).

Is it possible with passport.js to deal with 2 different ways to login? one for the AngularJS app with sessions and one stateless without having to make too many changes in my code ^^

Comment: I have similar question over here,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094710/local-and-social-authorization-with-node-js-on-mobile-app
it seems that such popular aspect of auth is not described anywhere precisely and it sucks :(

Comment: did you guys look at this [passport.js RESTful auth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572600/passport-js-restful-auth)