# Local and social authorization with node.js on mobile app

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Im running node.js server with mongodb as a DB, for local and FB auth from browser I use passport.js
How can I use both from mobile phone app? Can someone describe the flow precisely? Cause I couldnt really find precise explanation of such flow

few points that I dont get in the flow right away:

1. How req.isAuthenticated is working with iphone apps
2. How fb strategies work for iphone app?

Answer (score 0):

Try following scenario:

1. You can use [facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) for login via iphone to get facebook access token
2. Then authenticate facebook access token with your server using [passport-facebook-token](https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token)

I hope this scenario can help you.